# web.config default error page conflicting with 404 returned from API

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, custom-error-pages

How do I prevent IIS 8 from intercepting HTTP 404 errors and handling them (via `<httpError>` or `<customError>`) when the `AngularJS` controller that called the API is expected to deal with the 404? The 404 the API call returns simply means that the object requested was not found. Yet IIS seems to intercept the 404 and treat is as an error.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" defaultPath="Error.html">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <remove statusCode="505" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="Error.html" />
    <error statusCode="505" path="Error.html" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I could disable the custom error handling in the web.config (above) but I still want a default catch all error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the base controller's  `protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)` You can set the `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true`. This will instruct IIS to ignore custom errors that you have defined.

See [this](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html) article for more detail in catching 404's in the controller.